# Why can only certain compiler apps write to internal storage?

Tags: android, file, compiler-errors, permissions

I'm programming in Java on my Samsung Galaxy S9+, and my program creates and writes to files. When I run the code in the app Online Compiler, it successfully writes to the files, but when I run it in other compiler apps such as Dcoder or Java N-IDE, it returns errors saying "Read-only file system" or "Permission denied".

I would be alright with just using Online Compiler if it weren't for the fact that Online Compiler asks for all runtime inputs upfront, which doesn't allow for more than one set of inputs. My program requires that functionality because it allows the user to choose a method which then takes input.

I'm asking this question in hopes that the answer may lead me to a way to make Dcoder or Java N-IDE get the same permissions as Online Compiler. If that's not possible, then I'd be grateful if someone could recommend an Android compiler app that has both write permissions *and* multiple input functionality.

As a side note, in my research, I found a lot of questions talking about Android app developing and using a .xml Android manifest file to request permissions. That sounds like it's talking about developing sellable apps for the Android platform, which isn't what I'm doing. I'm just writing a simple Java program for myself that needs to write to files. I may share this program with a friend to use on their phone at some point, but that's the furthest I plan to take it.

Comment: `app Online Compiler` ? What is that? `other compiler apps such as Dcoder or Java N-IDE` I have no idea where this is about. What about using Android Studio and an Android phone or emulator?

Comment: Android manifest file is needed for every app. Has nothing to do with selling or play store.

Comment: I think i start to understand. But what is multiple input functionality?

Comment: What about AIDE?

Comment: I'm not writing an app. I downloaded an app called Online Compiler from the Play Store, which lets me write and compile programs. This app (Online Compiler) can write to files, while the other two apps I've tried (Dcoder and Java N-IDE) don't have permission. I would like to know why. For now, I can enter my inputs separated by a newline and use a public static Scanner declared above main to enter both sets of inputs, but I would like to find an app that doesn't ask for all inputs up front so I can actually interact with the user prompts I wrote instead of entering everything without a prompt.

Comment: I think you have these problems only on an Android Q+ device?

Comment: What does Q+ have to do with programming on my smartphone? I just googled Android Q+ and it says it's a TV box...

Comment: If you would just answer my question then i could tell you what it had to do with yoir problem. Android 10/Q. Android 11.

Comment: I see that you're an expert on Android development. This question isn't about that. Unfortunately, it attracted you because the terminology is very similar. In the last paragraph of my post, I explained that I kept finding answers online about Android development when trying to research this question. But since I'm not developing an app, they didn't help me. I hope you can understand now. Basically, this question isn't for you. Unless you also happen to know about a variety of programming apps available on the Play Store.

Comment: A lot of words (pretty unkindly too by the way). Still: if you just would answer my question you could be helped as things go futher as you are thinking now or can imagine.

Comment: I'm programming on a Samsung Galaxy S9+.

Comment: Yes i knew that. You told that before. My question was different though.

Comment: It says it's Android version 9.

Comment: Ok. Then i cannot help you.